# SQL Update Parameters Using Template Fields in Gridview

Tags: sql, asp.net, gridview

I have given my sqldatasource an update statement and the parameters have been generated, i.e...

```
<asp:Parameter Name="Name" />
```

Gowever when I enter edit mode within the gridview, type in a new value and then press to accept the changes the gridview refreshes with the old values as if it was never updated (and it isn't).

I'm unsure if this is because I am using template fields?

```
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Address1" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Address2" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Address3" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Address4" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Address5" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PostCode" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Tel" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Fax" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="OpLicense" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="DispNumber" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="DispRenewed" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="DispExp" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Email" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" />
        </UpdateParameters>
```

Comment: And how are you binding data to gridview?

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ SQLDataSource

Comment: Can you put `page_load` code in your question.

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ My page load is empty.

Answer (score 0):

post your parameters like this:

```
<UpdateParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
</UpdateParameters>
```